# what is shouldFail in groovy?

Tags: groovy, closures

How does the code within the 'shouldFail?' block work? I understand that it is a closure, but the code gets called regardless of whether or not I call is using its signature. Besides, what's the deal with the "ReadOnlyPropertyException" showing up in the parenthesis? If it is a parameter, then it is not setup as listed in the official documentation!!

Questions: What is 'shouldFail'? How should it be invoked? How to handle the exception purportedly thrown by this method/function/closure?

```
void test02_ReadOnlyFieldInGroovyBean() {
    // You've probably noticed how Groovy automatically generates getters/setters for you. But what if you don't
    // want to generate a setter because it's a read-only field? Just mark it with 'final'. Groovy will understand.

    // Try to modify Ken's ssn. You should get a ReadOnlyPropertyException.
    def person = new GroovyPerson('Ken', 'Kousen', '7878')
    def failed = false

    shouldFail (ReadOnlyPropertyException) {
        // ------------ START EDITING HERE ----------------------
        System.out.println(" i am in should fail")
        person.ssn='8332';
        // ------------ STOP EDITING HERE  ----------------------
        failed = false
        System.out.println(" exiting should fail")
    }

    //def foobar=shouldFail("hjh");
    //def foobar=true;
    failed=shouldFail('abc');

    //System.out.println("Failed: "+failed);
    assert failed

    // The code wrapping your additions verifies that the ReadOnlyProperty exception has been thrown.
    // The curly brackets ({}) represent a closure. We'll get into what that means very soon.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shouldFail()` (in this variant) takes a class and a closure.  It runs the closure and reports a test failure if the closure does NOT exit by throwing an exception of that type.  As to catching the exception, you don't - `shouldFail()` does that for you.

See: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/test/GroovyAssert.html#shouldFail%28java.lang.Class,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29

(Reading the comments and the code around them, it looks like this unit test should *pass* because setting the `.ssn` property of `GroovyPerson` will *fail* as it is a read-only property, causing a `ReadOnlyPropertyException`.)

Comment: very interesting.. so it's a library function!! arghhh !

Comment: Yes.  Part of the Groovy-enhanced unit test facilities provided in `groovy.test` (which is building on JUnit).

Comment: But I'm still not sure I get it completely. The method accepts a) a class, b) a closure. So, shouldn't it be called as follows: shouldFail(ReadOnlyPropertyException, { /* code that throws this exception } ) ?? But it's called as follows: shouldFail (ReadOn...) { /* code that fails */ }  (( or at least that's how I think it's been called ))

Comment: daggun it... the thing works fine doing this as well: i.e. shouldFail(ReadOnlyPropertyException, { /* code that throws this exception } )

Comment: I believe either will work.  But when the last parameter to a method is a closure you are permitted to place it after the closing parenthesis as well as in the 'normal' position for an argument (before).

Comment: ahh haa ... I know I read that on passing somewhere! :) Thanks though! Kinda driving me crazy here.